# Get Layout XML to CustomView Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-custom-view

This is a Very simple layout I hope to achieve on. However, I tried many ways to make my customView appear at the side of the Buttons - LinearLayout. But I failed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

[image: Ideal Layout]

This is where I declare my CustomView at MainActivity.

```
public class Drawing extends Activity {

   mContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.labelCreator);

   mSignature = new Resize(this, null);

   mContent.addView(mSignature);
...........
```

My XML Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/Drawing"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/interface2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="#8b5a2b"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TableLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


                        <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/tableRow9"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                            <TableLayout
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                                <TableRow
                                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                                    <Button
                                        android:id="@+id/btnPhoto"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:drawableTop="@drawable/camera2"
                                        android:text="Camera"
                                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                                        android:textSize="25sp"
                                        android:typeface="serif" />

                                    <Button
                                        android:id="@+id/btnImage"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:drawableTop="@drawable/image"
                                        android:text="Image"
                                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                                        android:textSize="25sp"
                                        android:typeface="serif" />

                                </TableRow>

                                <TableRow
                                    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                                    <Button
                                        android:id="@+id/btnText"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:drawableTop="@drawable/text"
                                        android:text="Text"
                                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                                        android:textSize="25sp"
                                        android:typeface="serif" />

                                    <EditText
                                        android:id="@+id/editText1"
                                        android:layout_width="180dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:ems="10"
                                        android:freezesText="false"
                                        android:hint="text"
                                        android:maxLength="10"
                                        android:maxLines="1"
                                        android:textAlignment="center"
                                        android:textColor="#e6e6fa"
                                        android:textSize="25sp"
                                        android:typeface="serif"
                                        android:visibility="visible" />

                                </TableRow>

                                <TableRow
                                    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                                    <Spinner
                                        android:id="@+id/color_spinner"
                                        android:layout_width="135dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:textAlignment="center" />

                                    <Spinner
                                        android:id="@+id/fonts_spinner"
                                        android:layout_width="132dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:textAlignment="center"
                                        app:context=".LabelCreator" />

                                </TableRow>

                                <TableRow
                                    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                                    <Button
                                        android:id="@+id/btnSave"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:drawableTop="@drawable/save3"
                                        android:text="Save"
                                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                                        android:textSize="25sp"
                                        android:typeface="serif" />

                                    <Button
                                        android:id="@+id/btnClear"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:drawableTop="@drawable/clear"
                                        android:text="Clear"
                                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                                        android:textSize="25sp"
                                        android:typeface="serif" />

                                </TableRow>
                            </TableLayout>

                        </TableRow>

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btnClose"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:drawableRight="@drawable/close"
                            android:shadowColor="#00000000"
                            android:text="Close"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="25sp"
                            android:typeface="serif" />

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/btnAbout"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="About"
                                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                                android:textSize="25sp"
                                android:typeface="serif" />

                </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a structure to follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSave"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/save3"
            android:text="Save"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnClear"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/clear"
            android:text="Clear"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/color_spinner"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/fonts_spinner"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:context=".LabelCreator" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="7" >
// your custom view(Drawing area) will be here.
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here the parent layout has `android:orientation="horizontal"`  
 so all its child layout will display in column-wise.
If you want row-wise display make `android:orientation="vertical"`. Here I use vertical for the parent layout that have `<Button>` and `<Spinner>` controls.

 you will make changes in it as per your need.
Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for your help. What You are doing is putting the controls on top?

Comment: you can also put scroll view as a parent of all controls so you can put as many control as possible. but this is just a suggestion

Comment: you can make change in it as per your requirements :)